# PDFBox PDFMergerUtility: how do I tell which sources failed?

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox, unparseable

So, I'm doing this:

```
PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility();

for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) 
    mergePdf.addSource(filePaths.get(i));

mergePdf.setDestinationFileName(tempFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
mergePdf.mergeDocuments();
```

Which works great until an exception is thrown on a PDF it can't parse (either corrupt PDF or something PDFBox can't handle). It doesn't happen very often.

I would like to be able to tell which source(s) it failed on, exclude them in a subsequent merge and tell the user which documents failed.

Can this be done?

UPDATE:

Here's my exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error: Expected a long type at offset 591535, instead got 'E^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^UZí^KÄ@©¢^X<8d>G §ÑE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^TQE^T<84>f<96><8a>'
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLong(BaseParser.java:1695)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readObjectNumber(BaseParser.java:1623)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:614)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1220)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1187)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:237)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:194)
    at myapp.util.DocumentImage.combinePDFs(DocumentImage.java:289)
    at myapp.webapp.download.DownloadLatestForCLO.generate(DownloadLatestForCLO.java:73)
    at myapp.webapp.download.DownloadLatestForCLO.getFileSize(DownloadLatestForCLO.java:64)
    at myapp.webapp.download.DownloadServlet.handleRequest(DownloadServlet.java:58)
    at myapp.webapp.download.DownloadServlet.doGet(DownloadServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: According to the stack trace the exception occurs in `PDDocument.load`. Simply load those documents yourself.

Comment: What version are you using? The current versions are 1.8.11 or 2.0 RC3. If you are using 1.8.11, use the mergeDocumentsNonSeq() method.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily **PDFBox** is **Opensource** so having downloaded the latest source (2.00 RC3 at the time of writing) and in the file
`\pdfbox-2.0.0-RC3\pdfbox\src\main\java\org\apache\pdfbox\multipdf\PDFMergerUtility.java` (around line 188)

We can see that it throws this exception up from a lower level and does not catch it and add details of the file that caused the error.

***Until this is fixed* you will have to catch this error in your code and iterate each of the source files loading and closing them until you find the one(s) that won't be able to be processed and report this yourself.**

If you are interested in fixing the problem at source (inside **PDFBox**) then this is the edit to make and submit to the PDFBox project team.  When that fix is incorporated into a build and you upgrade to that version you can safely remove your iteration code:

```
        try
        {
            MemoryUsageSetting partitionedMemSetting = memUsageSetting != null ? 
                    memUsageSetting.getPartitionedCopy(sources.size()+1) :
                    MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly();
            Iterator<InputStream> sit = sources.iterator();
            destination = new PDDocument(partitionedMemSetting);

            while (sit.hasNext())
            {
                sourceFile = sit.next();
                source = PDDocument.load(sourceFile, partitionedMemSetting);
                tobeclosed.add(source);
                appendDocument(destination, source);
            }
            if (destinationStream == null)
            {
                destination.save(destinationFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                destination.save(destinationStream);
            }
        }
```

### catch (IOException e) { /* Insert code to place this in an inner exception and throw one including the named 'sourceFile' */ }

---

```
        finally
        {
            ....}
```

Comment: The addSource method does not throw an Exception (you're simply building a list of PDFs to merge). Its' the mergeDocuments method that throws the exception.

Comment: sorry - meant the Merge op.  If the merge op blows if one of the sources isn't a PDF and the exception it gives you has no detail or inner that specifies the source file that failed, then you'll have to work it out yourself in the catch.

Comment: All of the sources are PDFs. They view fine in Adobe or Evince (Linux , Document Viewer). I've added the stack trace to the question above. How would you figure out which sources failed from that?

Comment: Okay, I see your edit now. That would technically work, but it would be nice if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: The stack tells you it failed reading offset 591535 of loading one of the files - but doesn't say which - not much you can do!  I know it isn't efficient, but you are only going to do the extra looping and loading when the attempted task has failed anyway - what is worse, waiting 20sec(say) and told something went wrong or 30sec and told why?

Comment: You're right. I've already started updating my code to catch the exception and then figure out which sources failed. It's far less elegant than what I had. Later, I will put together a patch to submit to Apache.

Comment: If this worked, would you mind marking it as an answer? Cheers.

Comment: Your answer needs to more succinct. It should be narrowed down to "catch the error and in the catch block iterate the docs loading and closing each one until you find the one(s) that won't load."

Comment: Edited to be clearer.  I still left the original PDFBox code in there as I think it is important to encourage fixing at source if we have access via Opensource projects.